# Qt3D shader graph with uniform vec3 array

Tags: qt, opengl, shader, fragment-shader, qt3d

## Update

So by printing the compiled shader code from the `QShaderProgramBuilder` I found out that the shader nearly works and the only issue is the call to `renderClicks`. This line

```
fragColor = (((renderClicks(clicks[10], colors[10], (((((((phongFunction(ka, kd, ks, shininess, worldPosition, normalize(((eyePosition - worldPosition))), normalize(worldNormal)))))))))))));
```

should look like this

```
fragColor = (((renderClicks(clicks, colors, (((((((phongFunction(ka, kd, ks, shininess, worldPosition, normalize(((eyePosition - worldPosition))), normalize(worldNormal)))))))))))));
```

but since the names of the uniforms are `clicks[10]` and `colors[10]` I'm not sure if that is fixable.

---

## The Problem

I'm using `QSceneLoader` in my project to load objects automatically. Now I want to visualize clicks on the 3D surface of the objects. To this end, I'm traversing the entity hierarchy created by the scene loader until I reach a `QShaderProgramBuilder`. Next, I'm replacing the fragment shader graph in the shader program builder using `setFragmentShaderGraph` - you cannot supply a textfile containing normal shader code unfortunately.

I used the [default phong graph from GitHub](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/dev/src/extras/shaders/graphs/phong.frag.json) as a starting point and added my own uniforms - the clicks and the colors of the clicks, both `vec3` arrays. Unfortunately, the shader doesn't work until I remove the array definition from both.

**When I remove the array definition everwhere (i.e. `vec3 clicks` instead of `vec3 clicks[10]`) and pass a `QVector3D` instead of a `QVector<QVector3D>` I get the normal scene rendered.**

I also can't find the Qt3D node editor [mentioned here](https://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/qt3d_node_editor_and_shader_generator.pdf) but I doubt that it would solve my problem because in the videos that are on YouTube there don't seem to be any options to declare an array.

#### So, any ideas how I can properly use uniform arrays in the shader graph?

---

*Note: I already checked the OpenGL version which is 4.6 so that shouldn't be the issue.*

*Note 2: If someone needs a sample project let me know. I started to create one but it became rather large even though I tried to keep it small. It's not finished yet but I could complete it and upload it to GitHub.*

---

## The Code

This is the way I'm supplying the data from C++ as a parameter:

```
Qt3DRender::QParameter *clicksParameter = new Qt3DRender::QParameter(QStringLiteral("clicks"), m_clicks.constData());
```

I altered the shader graph to include the following new `prototype`:

```
"prototypes": {
        "renderClicks": {
            "inputs": ["clicks[10]", "colors[10]", "currentColor"],
            "outputs": ["result"],
            "parameters": {
                "type": {
                    "type": "QShaderLanguage::VariableType",
                    "value": "QShaderLanguage::Vec4"
                 }
             },
             "rules": [{
                "format": {
                    "api": "OpenGLCoreProfile",
                    "major": 3,
                    "minor": 0
                 },
                 "headerSnippets": [
                    "#pragma include :shaders/poseeditor/clicksRendering.inc.frag"
                 ],
                 "substitution": "vec4 $result = renderClicks($clicks, $colors, $currentColor);"
            }]
        }
    },
"nodes": ...
```

which references the following shader code in `clicksRendering.inc.frag`:

```c
vec4 renderClicks(vec3 clicks[10], vec3 colors[10], vec4 currentColor) {
    return currentColor;
}
```

Then I added the following new `nodes`:

```
...
        {
            "uuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000026}",
            "type": "input",
            "parameters": {
                "name": "clicks[10]",
                "qualifier": {
                    "type": "QShaderLanguage::StorageQualifier",
                    "value": "QShaderLanguage::Uniform"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "QShaderLanguage::VariableType",
                    "value": "QShaderLanguage::Vec3"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "uuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000027}",
            "type": "input",
            "parameters": {
                "name": "colors[10]",
                "qualifier": {
                    "type": "QShaderLanguage::StorageQualifier",
                    "value": "QShaderLanguage::Uniform"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "QShaderLanguage::VariableType",
                    "value": "QShaderLanguage::Vec3"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "uuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000028}",
            "type": "renderClicks"
        },
...
```

I also altered the last edges such that the final phong color is passed through my custom function:

```
...
        {
            "sourceUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000026}",
            "sourcePort": "value",
            "targetUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000028}",
            "targetPort": "clicks"
        },
        {
            "sourceUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000027}",
            "sourcePort": "value",
            "targetUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000028}",
            "targetPort": "colors"
        },
        {
            "sourceUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000024}",
            "sourcePort": "outputColor",
            "targetUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000028}",
            "targetPort": "currentColor"
        },
        {
            "sourceUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000028}",
            "sourcePort": "result",
            "targetUuid": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000025}",
            "targetPort": "fragColor"
        }
...
```

---

## Additional Info

I tried to remove the `[10]` part from the `inputs` of the new `prototype`. This output an error and the faulty shader code:

```c
const int MAX_LIGHTS = 8;
const int TYPE_POINT = 0;
const int TYPE_DIRECTIONAL = 1;
const int TYPE_SPOT = 2;
struct Light {
    int type;
    vec3 position;
    vec3 color;
    float intensity;
    vec3 direction;
    float constantAttenuation;
    float linearAttenuation;
    float quadraticAttenuation;
    float cutOffAngle;
};
uniform Light lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
uniform int lightCount;

// Pre-convolved environment maps
struct EnvironmentLight {
    samplerCube irradiance; // For diffuse contribution
    samplerCube specular; // For specular contribution
};
uniform EnvironmentLight envLight;
uniform int envLightCount = 0;

#line 52

void adsModel(const in vec3 worldPos,
              const in vec3 worldNormal,
              const in vec3 worldView,
              const in float shininess,
              out vec3 diffuseColor,
              out vec3 specularColor)
{
    diffuseColor = vec3(0.0);
    specularColor = vec3(0.0);

    // We perform all work in world space
    vec3 n = normalize(worldNormal);
    vec3 s = vec3(0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < lightCount; ++i) {
        float att = 1.0;
        float sDotN = 0.0;

        if (lights[i].type != TYPE_DIRECTIONAL) {
            // Point and Spot lights

            // Light position is already in world space
            vec3 sUnnormalized = lights[i].position - worldPos;
            s = normalize(sUnnormalized); // Light direction

            // Calculate the attenuation factor
            sDotN = dot(s, n);
            if (sDotN > 0.0) {
                if (lights[i].constantAttenuation != 0.0
                 || lights[i].linearAttenuation != 0.0
                 || lights[i].quadraticAttenuation != 0.0) {
                    float dist = length(sUnnormalized);
                    att = 1.0 / (lights[i].constantAttenuation +
                                 lights[i].linearAttenuation * dist +
                                 lights[i].quadraticAttenuation * dist * dist);
                }

                // The light direction is in world space already
                if (lights[i].type == TYPE_SPOT) {
                    // Check if fragment is inside or outside of the spot light cone
                    if (degrees(acos(dot(-s, lights[i].direction))) > lights[i].cutOffAngle)
                        sDotN = 0.0;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Directional lights
            // The light direction is in world space already
            s = normalize(-lights[i].direction);
            sDotN = dot(s, n);
        }

        // Calculate the diffuse factor
        float diffuse = max(sDotN, 0.0);

        // Calculate the specular factor
        float specular = 0.0;
        if (diffuse > 0.0 && shininess > 0.0) {
            float normFactor = (shininess + 2.0) / 2.0;
            vec3 r = reflect(-s, n);   // Reflection direction in world space
            specular = normFactor * pow(max(dot(r, worldView), 0.0), shininess);
        }

        // Accumulate the diffuse and specular contributions
        diffuseColor += att * lights[i].intensity * diffuse * lights[i].color;
        specularColor += att * lights[i].intensity * specular * lights[i].color;
    }
}

vec4 phongFunction(const in vec4 ambient,
                   const in vec4 diffuse,
                   const in vec4 specular,
                   const in float shininess,
                   const in vec3 worldPosition,
                   const in vec3 worldView,
                   const in vec3 worldNormal)
{
    // Calculate the lighting model, keeping the specular component separate
    vec3 diffuseColor, specularColor;
    adsModel(worldPosition, worldNormal, worldView, shininess, diffuseColor, specularColor);

    // Combine spec with ambient+diffuse for final fragment color
    vec3 color = (ambient.rgb + diffuseColor) * diffuse.rgb
               + specularColor * specular.rgb;

    return vec4(color, diffuse.a);
}

#line 11
uniform vec3 clicks[10];
uniform vec3 colors[10];
vec4 renderClicks(vec3 clicks[10], vec3 colors[10], vec4 currentColor) {
    return currentColor;
}

#line 15
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = (((renderClicks(clicks[10], colors[10], (((((((phongFunction(ka, kd, ks, shininess, worldPosition, normalize(((eyePosition - worldPosition))), normalize(worldNormal)))))))))))));
}
```

So the shader looks good except for the call to `renderClicks(clicks[10], colors[10], ...)`. But I don't know if I can get rid of the `[10]` parts because that's their name.

Comment: I'm looking into the source code of shader graph, and I think maybe you could use "uniformArrayInput" for the "type" field, see [here](https://github.com/qt/qt3d/blob/6eaf8482bdc9fcc453457c6281cb84a1d62c0122/src/render/materialsystem/prototypes/default.json#L931)

Comment: Wow I think you're right! I solved it differently in the mean time (can't recall how right now) but I'll definitely look into this when I have time, thanks a lot!